# Font size of bookmarks and tabs got small for chrome in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: google-chrome, fonts, size

Suddenly my font size of bookmarks and tabs got small in ubuntu 16.04. what is the process to revert it back? I even tried reinstalling chrome but issue is still there.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HZziz.jpg)

Answer (score 17):

Got the solution.

To permanently get back to the nice, calming original scaling factor (=1), you need to edit Chrome's desktop file:

***sudo nano /usr/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop***

Find the line which contains the path to the binary and change it from

***Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable %U***

to

***Exec=/usr/bin/google-chrome-stable --force-device-scale-factor=1 %U***

Comment: I had to edit this line in `~/.local/share/applications/google-chrome.desktop` as well to get it to work for me.

Comment: This happened to me on update from 56>57. Edited this, restarted chrome, and no change. Tried setting it to a different value other than `1` and still no change. @Cobbles I tried the file path you mentioned but that doesn't exist for me (Ubuntu Mate)